# Change width of elements based on other floating elements in the same row

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm currently working on a Material design based website theme. the basic layout would be a wrapper div that contains all cards.
With (on desktop mode) the cards automatically taking the maximum width they need (aka, width:auto;).
All cards have a float:left;

I am trying to make a small piece of Javascript that only executes on a x screen width that will maximize the size of the cards so they will not leave gaps to the right of the rows.

The current code that would actually matter with what element they are for:
The CSS for the cards (All div elements with class 'card'):

```
.card {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  min-width: 300px;
  max-width:calc(50% - 50px); /* Stops cards from taking more then 50% of the screen */
  min-height:300px;
  border-radius: 2px;
  box-shadow: 0 8px 17px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0,     0.19);
  float:left;
  margin:5px;
  padding:10px 20px;
  z-index: 1;
}
```

As everything should be dynamic and work across all types of monitors and orientations, there is no way to isolate the divs in a parent div to assist the resizing. What I have been thinking of (but have no idea of how to write it) would be using the Y coordinates (or JQuery's .offset().top) and find divs on the same X-position then give them a width based on the number of divs with one x-coordinate.

The (beta) website is online [here](http://zerothe3rd.16mb.com/)

I hope someone who know JQuery and JS better then me could help me with this. Thanks in advance!
A JS N00B

Comment: really not clear what you are wanting at various sizes but css media queries should do what you want. Also `flex` has a `justify` property depending on browser support you want

Comment: @charlietfl For example: the screen width is 100. there's 4 divs on one line with the sizes 10, 25, 35 and 15 (so a total of 85) the remaining 15 is nothing, which I do not want. So the JS or if possible CSS should make the 4 divs X wide so they total 100. Problem being is that I need a universal solution that would cover the same thing as described for 2-endless dives on one row without them floating to the next line.

Answer (score 0):

Well, anyone interested, I found out that JS for this one is totally unuseful if you're not planning on going super far with backward compatibility.

Thanks to @charlietfl for pointing me towards the whole CSS3 `flex` thing, this solved pretty much all troubles and did exactly what I needed. Thanks charlietfl!